# Unknown glassware please help, vshaped with a small bulb on one side, hollow but narrow to both sides!

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, equipment

Looking to try an identify some glassware we have found in a cupboard. This is just the start of it... 
1 item here, v-shaped, small bulb but hollow, narrow entrance and exit... 
[image: item 1]

Comment: In advance, I'd suggest to post one piece of equipment per question and make the title of each question more descriptive, e.g. "Name for an Y-shaped glass tube with a bulge" or something along these lines. Dimensions and comments on the construction details are also welcomed.

Comment: As for the question, this somewhat looks like a [viscosimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscometer).

Comment: No idea what it is, but I don't think that it is a viscometer.

Comment: @MaxW Yeah, this Y-shape would make little sense for a visco; that's why I used "*looks like*" :) (Cf. "*A policeman attempted to rob me*" and "*A person who looked like a policeman attempted to rob me*".)

Comment: This was a volumetric pipette for sure, which was converted into a home-made crude viscometer. One can see the remaining brown ring on the left arm. One end of the pipette was elongated to reduce the diameter. Fill the bulb with water and see how quickly it drains. If you share the background that would be better to id i.e. whose cupboard was that?

Comment: Unfortunately we have no idea who's cupboard it was... We did wonder if it was a homemade item... and we have a fear we have a lot more upon emptying boxes yesterday. We found more of these items that we can definitely see the fill line and volume from a pipette. At least if we have an idea what it is a crude item of it may be possible to use/offer to academics. Many thanks!

Comment: Rather than a viscometer it could just be a nice homemade trap for an air-sensitive reaction that is producing gas (e.g. fermentation). The reaction would be in a vessel attached to the left side, and liquid would be in the lower part of the U shape. Produced gas would escape, but no gas would come in as long as the pressure is higher in the vessel than outside. The bulb is there so that if a burst of gas pushes the liquid up out of the trap (or if liquid escapes from the reaction vessel), it falls and collects in the bulb rather than going out the tube and contaminating whatever is out there.